# I was trying to create register page by using `UserCreationForm` but getting empty `QueryDict` from post method

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, django-templates

I was trying to create register page by using `UserCreationForm` but getting empty  `QueryDict` from post method when I print it on console. There is no errors. I did research on it but could not figure it out.

this is `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    print('\n\n\n\n',request.POST,'\n\n\n')
    if request.method   == 'POST':
        form=UserCreationForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('home/')
    else:
        form=UserCreationForm()
    context={'form':form}   

    return render(request,'register/register.html',context)
```

and this is my template:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" class="form-group" action="#%">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit", name="register", value="register1", class="btn btn-success" > Register </button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I hit register button on website I am getting this traceback:

```
September 21, 2023 - 10:00:05
Django version 4.2.5, using settings 'proproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

<QueryDict: {}> 

[21/Sep/2023 10:00:11] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3702

<QueryDict: {}> 

[21/Sep/2023 10:00:11] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3702
```

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your form but not supplying any data to it. Change:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm() #thisline
```

To:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
```

Should fix the empty dict you are getting back.

Comment: Actually I already tried this, now I tried it again but result is same

Comment: I guess I found something could help: code not printing `request.POST` when I hit the register button it is printing when refresh the page
and it is not giving error even if I enter password incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be `form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)` instead of `form=UserCreationForm()`. because you are sending an empty form like that in the code. You have to populate the form by `request.POST`.

Comment: Actually I already tried this, now I tried it again but result is same

Comment: I guess I found something could help: code not printing request.POST when I hit the register button it is printing when refresh the page and it is not giving error even if I enter password incorrectly